# How to change selected tab by redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, tabs

I have the following issue.

I am making a redirection to the following page "http://localhost/account#tab-verification".
Once the user is on that page, I want the corresponding tab to be active.

Here is some of my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="profile-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" id="personal-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-personal">Personal</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="verification"><a class="nav-link" id="verification-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-verification">ID Verification</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<hr />
<br>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-personal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-tab">
    
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-verification" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="verification-tab">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS code I am including at the bottom of my page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    ...
    var tabId = window.location.hash;
    // Select the tab
    // $('#profile-tab a:last').tab('show');
    $('#profile-tab a[href="' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
});
</script>
```

I tried different options and no one is making another tab then the default active.
There are also no errors In the console. I am assuming the problem be something with the included bootstrap/jquery?

Comment: Your tabs are based on active classes ```active```, apply those to the correct tab.

Comment: Are you getting value for tabId when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the different css & js bootstrap versions.
Once I fixed that, this is the code needed to work properly:

```
var tabId = window.location.hash;
var firstTabEl = document.querySelector('#profile-tab a[href="' + tabId + '"]');
var firstTab = new bootstrap.Tab(firstTabEl);
firstTab.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to produce the desired result by using just the commented line from your provided code, as shown below. Perhaps there is additional context that could explain your issue?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#profile-tab a:last').tab('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem statement is not just showing the tab, but giving active class after the page has loaded

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet is working, classes for active tab-pane are `tab-pane fade active in`, classes for active nav-item `nav-item active`. nav-link does not require any active class.

```js
$(function () {
    var tabId = window.location.hash;
    // Select the tab
    // $('#profile-tab a:last').tab('show');
    $('#profile-tab a[href="' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="profile-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item active" role="presentation">
        <a class="nav-link" id="personal-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-personal">Personal</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="verification">
        <a class="nav-link" id="verification-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab-verification">ID Verification</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br>
<hr />
<br>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab-personal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="personal-tab">
        tab-personal
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-verification" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="verification-tab">
        tab-verification
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately on my website that is not working. with the class changes, it doesn't show the active tab either. I am using this bootstrap version: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Can be that the reason?

Comment: I think css is of bootstrap v5.*. The above snippet is using bootstrap 3.3.7, so bootstrap js and css is of same version.

Comment: I see in provided code cdn for bootstrap js is of v3.7.7, so css also to be is of v3.7.7.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to trigger a click on the tab.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    ...
    var tabId = window.location.hash;
    // Click the tab
    $('#profile-tab a[href="' + tabId + '"]').click();
  });
</script>
```